# Phonegap Build: Notification / Popup not working in android?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova

this is the portion of code i get from the web to implement the notification, it worked when i do in browser testing but i don't know why it's not working when i use the same code in my phone running android. the application couldn't run on iOS as well.

```
navigator.notification.alert(
    'Please enter correct username and password',  // message
             null,         // callback
    'Information',            // title
        'Okay'                  // buttonName
);
```

Comment: Have u tried with `alert(message);` . I have used like this its also works fine, `navigator.notification.alert('message');`

Comment: @TrackRuler, Bro, It's not working :(

Comment: Found the solution. Simply alert("Something");

Answer (score 0):

Simply alert(message); but no need the long line of text.